# Bug Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent()

Tags: adminhtml, module, blocks

I try to create a module in the administration of my site.I have a mistake I can not seem to solve for many hours:

Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given,

here my config file :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Digitgold_Demande>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Digitgold_Demande>
    </modules>

       <global>
        <helpers>
            <listedemande>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Digitgold_ListeDemande_Helper</class>
            </listedemande>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <listedemande>
                <class>DigitGold_ListeDemande_Block</class>
            </listedemande>
        </blocks>

    </global>

    <admin>
         <routers>
             <test>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                   <module>Digitgold_ListeDemande</module>
                   <frontName>adminlisteclient</frontName>
                </args>
             </test>
          </routers>
     </admin>
     <adminhtml>
       <menu>
          <customer>
              <children>    
                  <listedemande translate="title" module="listedemande">
                     <title>Demande client</title>
                     <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                     <action>adminlisteclient/liste/index</action>
                   </listedemande>
            </children>
          </customer>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

here my controller :

```
    class DigitGold_ListeDemande_ListeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

        protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        ->_setActiveMenu('customer/listedemande');
        return $this;
    }

        public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('listedemande/Adminhtml_Liste_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('listedemande'));

        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('listedemande/adminhtml_listdemande'))
            ->renderLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code in the block `'listedemande/adminhtml_listdemande'`

Answer (score 3):

`createBlock()` is an abstract factory pattern for Blocks inside of Magento.  Whenever Magento cannot resolve a factory class from this method, a boolean is returned.

Check your class `DigitGold_ListeDemande_Block_Adminhtml_ListDemande` for spelling, casing, or class related errors.  Also ensure that your class file is located at *app/code/local/DigitGold/ListeDemande/Block/Adminhtml/ListDemande.php*.